# How can you use Ajax to add a parsys to an Adobe CQ page?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, adobe, aem

I have a page in Adobe CQ 5.6 which has three separate parsys instances on the page, each of these has added to it a component which has a section of HTML added to it through an Ajax call. My end goal is to set up an AngularJS sub-page navigation which is still accessible to author editing.

Where I'm running into a problem is that these Ajax sections are pulling pages from within CQ which themselves contain parsys instances. However, these instances added through Ajax are not being initialized in the authoring environment, even though they are properly adding the HTML markup for the parsys section. I've also verified that the Ajax sections are creating new content nodes (under /content) with jcr:content child nodes.

It looks to me like what I need to do is call some javascript command to reinitialize the sidekick after each Ajax call which swaps out a parsys section on the page. I just have no idea what javascript function I'd call.

Does anyone know what this function is, or am I completely off base?

Here's the code from my mainmoduel.jap and shoes.jsp files. The angular.bootstrap at the end is necessary for dealing with multiple sibling modules on the page. All of this works if I don't use Ajax.

```
<%-- angularmainpage-simple.jsp --%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %><%
%><%
    // TODO add you code here
%><cq:include script="head.jsp" />
<cq:includeClientLib categories="angulardemo.all"/>

<div data-ng-app class="page-content bodyWidth" id="mainPageContainer">
    body
    <div class="row-fluid"><%-- row-fluid here will enlarge the width to 100% --%>
        <div class="span12">
            <cq:include path="grid-12-par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
            <cq:include path="grid-8-par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <cq:include path="grid-4-par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
<%-- shoes.jsp --%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
    <div id="shoesComponent" class="angularComponent">
    <div data-ng-controller="shoesController">
        <h4>Name: {{name}}</h4>
        <div data-ng-view>
        </div>
        <h5>Sub-Parsys:</h5>
        <div>
            <cq:include path="shoes-par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-list" navlist>
            <li class="nav-header">{{name}} pages:</li>
            <li class="active" ng-click="setActive($event)">
                <a href="#/route1">Route 1</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-click="setActive($event)">
                <a href="#/route2">Route 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function shoesController ($scope) {
$scope.name = "Shoes Module";
}
var shoesModule = angular.module('shoesMod', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/route1', {templateUrl: 'home/shoes/route1.html', controller: shoesController}).
        when('/route2', {templateUrl: 'home/shoes/route2.html', controller: shoesController}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/route1'});
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('shoesComponent'), ['shoesMod']);
</script>
```

The routes are simply:

```
<%-- partial.jsp --%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %><%
%><%
    // TODO add you code here
%><div>Partial Parsys for CQ Resource "<%=currentPage.getTitle() %>"</div>
<div>Need to call some script here to initialize the parsys component below.</div>
<div><cq:include path="partial-par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
```

Comment: It occurred to me that Adobe CQ uses ExtJS for its interface, so I've been doing some digging through the ExtJS docs to try and find some way to reinitialize all the widgets on a page. So far, I haven't found anything, but thought I'd expand the conversation a bit to include this library.

Comment: Perhaps I could do this by forcing the added parsys to be added through Ext.ComponentMgr.register(Ext.Component)?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the REST interface, authoring changes boil down to POST statements.

You can reverse-engineer the statements by watching the network traffic (ie Chrome Dev Tools network tab) while editing via the built-in GUI authoring.

For instance:

http://{instance:port}/content/geometrixx/en/products/jcr:content/par/7_1204885810609
form data: (url encoded)

```
.%2Fsling%3AresourceType:foundation%2Fcomponents%2Ftext
.%2Fjcr%3AlastModified:
.%2Fjcr%3AlastModifiedBy:
_charset_:utf-8
%3Astatus:browser
.%2Ftext:%3Cp%3EThe%20triangle%20is%20an%20old%20favorite.%20It%20combines%20the%20simplicity%20of%20three-sidedness%20with%20the%20reliability%20of%20having%20only%20two%20dimensions.%20And%20with%20the%20new%20finds%20off%20the%20coast%20of%20Madagascar%20coming%20online%2C%20triangle%20prices%20are%20lower%20than%20ever!%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3EIf%20you%20like%20the%20look%20of%20the%20triangle%20but%20want%20to%20upgrade%20to%20three%20dimensions%2C%20why%20not%20take%20a%20look%20at%20the%20tetrahedron%3F%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3EChanged%3C%2Fp%3E%0A
.%2FtextIsRich:true
.%2Fcq%3AcssClass:%20
oldCqCssClass:%20
```

See also: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html